# git-daemon under systemd: base-path does not exist or is not a directory

Tags: git, systemd

I'm trying to enable access to my hosted GitLab server over `git` propocol using `git-daemon`. If I'm running git-daemon from command line it works as expected:

```
$ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-daemon --export-all --base-path=/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories --syslog --verbose

$ git ls-remote git://localhost/cm/test_project.git
9cbff8accfa291ffeb8189f114c6d290a3856511        HEAD
2817d289674481ef02f05c3558063a5239d844b2        refs/heads/develop2
9cbff8accfa291ffeb8189f114c6d290a3856511        refs/heads/master
bce85bd749a69cb127bdb0e64c173e926eb77cbc        refs/heads/old-master
$
```

But if I'm running `git-daemon` as `systemd` unit I'm getting the following error:

```
$ git ls-remote git://localhost/cm/test_project.git
fatal: read error: Connection reset by peer
$
```

and in logs:

```
git-daemon[19089]: base-path '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories' does not exist or is not a directory
```

I have the following setup:

*git-daemon.socket:*

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/git-daemon.socket
[Unit]
Description=Git Activation Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:9418
Accept=true

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
$
```

*git-daemon@.service:*

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/git-daemon@.service
[Unit]
Description=Git Repositories Server Daemon
Documentation=man:git-daemon(1)

[Service]
User=nobody
ExecStart=-/usr/libexec/git-core/git-daemon --export-all --base-path=/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories --syslog --verbose
StandardInput=socket
$
```

Port `9418` is available:

```
$ netstat -nap | grep 9418
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9418            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
$
```

Directory exists:

```
$ stat /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
  File: ‘/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories’
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fc01h/64513d    Inode: 226543354   Links: 46
Access: (2770/drwxrws---)  Uid: (  500/     git)   Gid: (  500/     git)
Access: 2017-06-09 13:13:16.514659543 +0000
Modify: 2017-04-22 23:28:16.227301854 +0000
Change: 2017-04-22 23:28:16.227301854 +0000
 Birth: -
$
```

OS is `CentOS 7`, git version is `1.8.3.1`

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
$
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Is SELinux enabled and some policy is stopping the git daemon from accessing the directory? Any hints if you prefix /usr/libexec/git-core/git-daemon with `strace -o /tmp/git-daemon` and then look at any strace output in `/tmp`?

Comment: Hello, SELinux is disabled:
`$ sestatus
SELinux status:
                 disabled

$`

Thank you, I found that `User=nobody` has to be changed to `User=git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `User=nobody` has to be changed to `User=git` in */etc/systemd/system/git-daemon@.service* in order to fix the issue.